# Evaluate formula referencing external workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I have a Excel worksheet (named Parámetros) where I assign 3 values that will be parameters for my formula:

```
A1=Nombre archivo

B1=C:\Carpeta\[Nombre archivo.xlsx]

A2=Pestaña

B2=Hoja 1

A3=Valor

B3=$A$10
```

In another sheet, I want to create a formula that concatenate the three cells to obtain the cell value of a sheet from another file (per the what is specified in the parameters above) - the cell value is 150.

I do this formula:

```
="'"&Parámetros!B1&Parámetros!B2&"'!"&Parámetros!B3
```

Instead of returning the value of that cell, 150, what is returned to me is the concatenation of the values specified in the formula:

```
'C:\Carpeta\[Nombre archivo.xlsx]Hoja 1'!$A$10
```

If in the result cell I select the cell of the file in question, the result is correct (150) and in the formula bar I see the following formula:

```
='C:\Carpeta\[Nombre archivo.xlsx]Hoja 1'!$A$10
```

How do I return the correct value and not the concatenation of the values?

Comment: Try `INDIRECT` Formula

Comment: `=INDIRECT(Parámetros!B1 & Parámetros!B2 & "'!" & Parámetros!B3)`

Comment: Hello @nightcrawler23, I have tried this function and the result is an error (#¡REF!) . I have tried too this: =INDIRECT("'"&Parámetros!B1&Parámetros!B2&"'!"&Parámetros!B3)

Comment: `INDIRECT` works for me - try pasting your path in like this `=INDIRECT(just type it in)` and check it works. Then replace `just type it in` with your cell reference based on the parameters.

Comment: I write **=INDIRECT("D:\Documentación\Clientes\Excel\\[VARIABLES.xlsx]Data!$A$11")** and the result is an error formula. The path, the worksheet (Data) and the cell ($A11$) exists.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work when the "VARIABLES.xl‌​sx" file is closed. I can't test right now.

Comment: Yes, this is the problema. The source file must be open for the formula to work correctly. Thank you for your help.